# Orbeon Forms - Date Picker Changes to Wrong Date

Tags: scala, bootstrap-4, orbeon, xbl

When a user enters an invalid date into the date picker field for example, `99/99/99999` and the user clicks away causing the input to loose focus the date changes to `7/6/99999` which is undesirable as this will pass date validation and not strong smart entry support.

- I understand this is caused by `forceParse` a feature of the underlying [Bootstrap date picker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html).
- I also see this is set to `true` in the [Scala class implementing the date picker](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/def1c17b48a3236d614fdd45c031bccb0b7654a8/xforms/js/src/main/scala/org/orbeon/xbl/Date.scala).

Is there anyway to stop this behavior or set `forceParse` to false in the xbl component when configuring the form?

Answer (score 0):

This issue with inconsistent parsing of years above 10,000 is fixed in Orbeon Forms 2020.1 (which isn't yet released at the time of this writing). For more on this, see [#4637](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4637).

Comment: It also seems to be an issue if you enter 99/99/1999 and you get 7/6/1999. Are these issues also being addressed or can the `forceParse` been disabled as it changes the date which can then pass validation leading to bad data

Comment: You're right, the same logic applies to days and months, but in that case it seems to make more sense to me. The problem with years was, as mentioned in [#4637](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4637), that `202222` was accepted, but `2022222` was converted into the current year, because the later isn't a valid year in JavaScript, while both should most likely be considered as invalid. Hence we opted to *always* truncate the year if it had more than 4 digits.

Comment: But how do you change `99` to a valid month? Do you change it to `12`, because it is the closest number? Or September,  because the user is likely to have wanted to type just `9` and not `99`? Right now `99` is covered to the current month (August), which I agree is less likely to be correct as a guess. Out of those 3 options, it seems to be that truncating additional digits that make the number invalid is the option that makes the most sense for a month.

Comment: But for days, I'd say that if users type `31` for a month that only has 30 days, changing it to `30` (the "closest" heuristic) would make more sense than changing it to `3` (the "truncate" heuristic). But if users enter `222`, they're more likely to have meant `22` (the "truncate" heuristic) than `30` or `31` (the "closest" heuristic). Any thoughts? ‑Alex

Comment: I would agree with truncating to the closest possible day/month so, 99..n -> 9 and where a month has 30 days and a user enter 31 it becomes 30. I would also suggest an option to turn off `forceParse` given my use case I would rather give a validation exception or at least at minimum a field has changed warning rather than guess. I am looking to create a custom XBL component to get round this.

Comment: I would also prefer to *keep* invalid input that doesn't parse a valid date, and mark it as invalid, rather than trying to force it into a valid date, and, if we can't, clearing the field. Is removing `forceParse` enough to get that? I doubt it is ;). Are you interested in experimenting? Then please go ahead, and if you have some changes that you'd like to incorporate, feel free to submit a PR, or follow-up with comment here. Would that sound like a plan? ‑Alex